# What's a term to describe multiple shoulder surfing attacks to uncover different parts of the password?

Tags: attacks

Is there an existing term that describes shoulder surfing attacks where the adversary observes a different part of the password each time, to eventually construct the whole password?

An example would be focusing on the left part of the keyboard at an occasion, focusing on the right part at a different occasion, then combining the observations.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there is an official term. I might coin the phrase: "Constructive Shoulder Surfing" or "Iterative Shoulder Surfing"

Comment: I like "Iterative Shoulder Surfing" :)

Comment: Advanced Shoulder Surfing with Half Observable Length Enumeration

Comment: @this.josh I want to promote your term in hopes he actually uses it in an academic paper.

Answer (score 0):

The term `surveillance` comes to mind.